# Using client separately in python pyrogram

Tags: client, pyrogram

I have got this problem with pyrogram

```
app = Client("session",
        api_id,
        api_hash,
        bot_token)
```

How can i send message via bot not userbot ?

Comment: and also i want to get updates only with my bot not userbot. there was no docs to know that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You will need to include more details than that.  What problem do you have?  What is this userbot?

Comment: Thanks for your attention i mean in pyrogram library has two kinds there you can run bots and userbots at the same time but i want to use them separately like

@bot.handler()
@app.handler()

Answer (score 0):

for using a bot and a userbot separately in same time you should do this :

```
@bot.on_message ...
your code

@app.on_message 
your code 
 
bot.start()
app.run()
```

or you can use 2 threads with using threading mudule.